# How to fix inline block's container "1px border bottom"-like without float

Tags: html, css

## The 1px vertical visual glitch

For an horizontal menu where I don't want to use floats, I have a small glitch which is a space of about 1px at the bottom of each LI container.

I tried to set the font size of the LI to 0, tried different values of vertical-align, overriding a potential border-bottom, but it still fails at least on chrome.

***Note:*** check it with Chrome, it's not a "space related issue" between LIs (the horizontal space is not a problem for me, I just wanted to show you the simplified version of my issue), neither a text-decoration one.

## Preview

[image: Preview, notice the red horizontal bar of the LI]

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a>
        Something
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
        Something else
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
        Something else 2
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Fiddle source:**
http://jsfiddle.net/darknessm0404/xjfd4p3z/

Notice that I do not want to use float because it creates some problem on complicated designs (with css clear properties for example).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use `display:table-cell`

Comment: Or remove the white space between each `<li>`.

Comment: As stated above, the problem isn't the blue spaces, it's the red bottom "margin-like".

Answer (score 3):

Add display to block to your links (li > a):

```
li > a {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

mention display:block in

```
li > a {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:block;
}
```

updated **[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/xjfd4p3z/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is the text-decoration property set to none on your links to remove the line. Try this: 
`li > a {
    background-color:yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}`